# Shuffle new characters after each character in a string

Tags: php, string, split, shuffle

I have the following function to generate a new random character at the beginning and at the end of a string:

```
function random($string) {

    $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $shuffle_start = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    $shuffle_end = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    $str = chunk_split($string, 1, substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 5));

    return $shuffle_start . $str . $shuffle_end;

}
```

As you can see for `$str` I'm trying to get 5 random characters after each letter in the string and it's that I need some help with. As it is now, this function prints this:

`dYj9quhDk2T4eDk2T4lDk2T4lDk2T4oDk2T4KHjN6T`

The string is "hello" and are covered by 6 random characters at the beginning and at the end of the string (`dYj9qu` and `KHjN6T`). After each character inside of this string, you can see `Dk2T4` and it's repeatably coming back after each character. This is not how I want it! I want `Dk2T4` to be random so the string would look like this:

`dYj9quhDk2T4eTft3bl7yjF4lac34vodkiY0KHjN6T`

I want also the last characters of the string ("hello" - in this case `dkiY0` in the last string) where removed from the string, so it looks like this:

`dYj9quhDk2T4eTft3bl7yjF4lac34voKHjN6T`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `chunk_split` evaluates the `substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 5)` only once. You need to iterate the letters and generate the sequence for each one:

```
function random($string) {

    $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $shuffle_start = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    $shuffle_end = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    $letters = str_split($string);
    $str = '';
    $count = count($letters);
    foreach($letters as $l){
        $count--;
        $str .= $l;
        if($count){ // add 5 characters if not last letter
            $str .= substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 5);
        }
    }

    return $shuffle_start . $str . $shuffle_end;
}
```

Comment: That solved the shuffle issue :) Many thanks! But how can I remove the last 5 characters as I described in my question?

Comment: @ErikEdgren Updated. Now last 5 characters are not appended.